# Using unix timestamp and making clients get token

Tags: timestamp

I'm trying to make a function that uses unix timestamp for setting a limited time and after the limited time is over I would like to make clients get their token by themselves Does anyone have any idea or help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example on how it could work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TimedTokenVault {
    uint256 startTime;

    function setStartTime(uint256 _startTime) public {
        // add access restrictions and/or make sure this can be called only once

        startTime = _startTime;
    }

    // Clients can call this after the startTime
    function requestToken() public {
        require(startTime > now, "Sorry, token requests is not open yet");

        // transfer token(s)
    }
}
```

The example is missing a lot of required code but you should get the idea. After checking the `startTime` in `requestToken` you can probably use regular token `transfer` method to transfer the tokens.